# There's a link between annihilating polynomials and annihilators (ring theory)?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

There's a link between annihilating polynomials described in Hoffman and Kunze in section 6.3 pg 190 and annihilator? I don't think it's just a case if these two concepts have similar names but maybe I'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

If $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $k$ and $M$ is an endomorphism of $V$, then $V$ is a module over the polynomial ring $k[x]$ by having $x^n$ act like $M^n$ and extending linearly.

The annihilator of $V$ will be the set of annihilating polynomials for $M$.